# Entity Object not persisting In H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, h2, in-memory-database

I have implemented integration test for my controller .

and I am trying to test The POST method which creates a new record .

My controller :-

```
package com.gasx.corex.scheduler.controller;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;

import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service.SchedulerJobServiceI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.SchedulerJob;
import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service.SchedulerJobService;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/gasx/restscd")
    public class SchedulerJobController {

        @Autowired
        private SchedulerJobServiceI schedulerJobService;



        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addschedulerjob")
        public void addSchedulerJob(@RequestBody SchedulerJob schedulerJob) {
            schedulerJobService.addSchedulerJob(schedulerJob);
        }

    }
```

My Service Class:-

```
package com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.SchedulerJob;
import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.rest.SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class SchedulerJobService implements SchedulerJobServiceI {

    @Autowired
    private SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI schedulerJobRestRepositoryI;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addSchedulerJob(SchedulerJob schedulerJob) {
        schedulerJobRestRepositoryI.save(schedulerJob);
    }

}
```

My Repository :-

```
package com.gasx.corex.scheduler.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.SchedulerJob;
import com.gasx.corex.ext.user.domain.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;

@Repository
@Transactional
//@Embeddable
//@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "schedulerJobs", path = "schedulerjobs")
public interface SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI extends CrudRepository<SchedulerJob, Integer> {
    List<Profile> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

My Spring Main Class:-

```
package com.gasx.corex.scheduler.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.gasx.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.gasx.*"})
//@EnableWebSecurity
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.gasx.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.gasx.*" )
public class SchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My aplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:corextrunk;Mode=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS corextrunk
spring.datasource.driverclassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=false
```

MY Console Output when executing save function:-

Hibernate: insert into scheduler_job (id, active, alb_endpoint, alb_jobuser, alb_payload, alb_prio, category, cron_expr, description, hook_script_name, hours, id_region, minutes, name, rest_endpoint_alias, rest_entity_content, rest_export_path, rest_media_type, rest_method, rest_url, run_archieve_lifespan, scheme, script_name, script_params, soap_send_action, shell_script_params, soap_action, soap_endpoint_alias, soap_export_path, soap_import_path, soap_payload, start_missed_run, time_control, timeout, type) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-12-14 14:34:35.270  INFO 6908 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-12-14 14:34:35.277  INFO 6908 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-14 14:34:35.281  INFO 6908 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-12-14 14:34:35.296  INFO 6908 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

**My Problem :-
I trued numerous examples on google but still I get no error on console ,insert executed but I cant see my record when I try to view the database from browser :-
URL I am using for viewing h2 database :- http://localhost:8081/h2-console
I even tried changing :--
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-update ( nonthing changed) 
removed spring.datasource.platform=h2 from my properties file ,still nothing chnaged .**

I am using springBoot and H2 in memory database .

not to forget my Integration test class :=

```
package com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.integrationtest.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.gasx.corex.base.configuration.CoreConfiguration;
import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.SchedulerJob;
import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.utils.SchedulerJobType;

import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.rest.SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI;
import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service.SchedulerJobService;
import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service.SchedulerJobServiceI;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;

import java.util.Base64;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT  , properties = {
        "management.server.port=0", "management.context-path=/admin" ,"security.basic.enabled=false"} )
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration( classes = {AllowAnonymousWebAccess.class  } )
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ComponentScan("com.gasx.*")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-testing-h2.properties")
public class SchedulerJobTestInt {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port  ;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void addSchedulerJobIntTest() throws  Exception{
        SchedulerJob schedulerJob = new SchedulerJob();
        schedulerJob.setName("ALB Cleanup");
        schedulerJob.setDescription("Cleanup of alb jobs. Please do not deactivate!");
        schedulerJob.setType(SchedulerJobType.REST);
        schedulerJob.setActive(true);
        schedulerJob.setStartMissedRun(false);
        schedulerJob.setCategory("SYSTEM");
        schedulerJob.setCronExpression(null);
        schedulerJob.setScheme("testScheme");
        schedulerJob.setIdRegion(1);
        schedulerJob.setAlbEndpoint("testAlbEndPoint");
        schedulerJob.setAlbPayload("SCHED_ALB");
        schedulerJob.setAlbPrio(1);
        schedulerJob.setAlbJobUser("MKRAUS");
        schedulerJob.setScriptParams("testScriptParams");
        schedulerJob.setShellScriptParams("clear_tmp 15");
        schedulerJob.setSoapEndpointAlias("");
        schedulerJob.setSoapImportPath("CORE/CORE2003/imp/price");
        schedulerJob.setSoapExportPath("testExportPath");
        schedulerJob.setSoapPayload("<api:readPartnersByIdRequest>");
        schedulerJob.setSoapAction("urn:readPartnersById");
        schedulerJob.setRestEndpointAlias("testEndpointAlias");
        schedulerJob.setRestUrl("testUrl");
        schedulerJob.setRestEntityContent("");
        schedulerJob.setRestExportPath("testRestExportPath");
        schedulerJob.setHookScriptName("testHookScriptName");
        schedulerJob.setMinutes("");
        schedulerJob.setHours("");




        mockMvc.perform(post("/gasx/restscd/addschedulerjob").content(asJsonString(schedulerJob))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }



}
```

Comment: I wrote that I don't get any error , .save() executes normally, the query is printed on the console , but I can see the record in the database

Comment: plz help anybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Controller :

```
package com.gasx.corex.scheduler.controller;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;

import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service.SchedulerJobServiceI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.SchedulerJob;
import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service.SchedulerJobService;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/gasx/restscd")
    public class SchedulerJobController {

        @Autowired
        private SchedulerJobService schedulerJobService;



        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addschedulerjob")
        public void addSchedulerJob(@RequestBody SchedulerJob schedulerJob) {
            schedulerJobService.addSchedulerJob(schedulerJob);
        }

    }
```

The service :

```
package com.gasx.corex.scheduler.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.SchedulerJob;
import com.gasx.corex.scheduler.rest.SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class SchedulerJobService implements SchedulerJobServiceI {

    @Autowired
    private SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI schedulerJobRestRepositoryI;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addSchedulerJob(SchedulerJob schedulerJob) {
        SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI.save(schedulerJob);
    }

}
```

The repository:

```
package com.gasx.corex.scheduler.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.gasx.corex.ext.scheduler.domain.SchedulerJob;
import com.gasx.corex.ext.user.domain.Profile;

public interface SchedulerJobRestRepositoryI extends JpaRepository<SchedulerJob, Integer> {
    List<SchedulerJob> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Your application yaml :

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate: 
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show-sql: false  
        format_sql: true
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 50
  h2:    
    console:
      enabled: false
      settings:
        trace: false
  batch:
    table-prefix: My_
    initializer:
      enabled: false

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:MYBASE;Mode=Oracle;
    platform: h2
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    continue-on-error: true
```

Your Main Class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({
    "fullPackage.controller",
    "fullPackage.service"
    })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "fullPackage.repository"     
   })
@EntityScan(basePackages= {
    "fullPackage.entity"
    })
public class SchedulerApplication { 
}
```

Your test Class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT  , properties = {
        "management.server.port=0", "management.context-path=/admin" ,"security.basic.enabled=false"} )
@ContextConfiguration( classes = {AllowAnonymousWebAccess.class  } )
@AutoConfigureMockMvc // i do not why you use it ?
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-testing-h2.properties")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"fullPackage.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"fullPackage.repository"}
public class SchedulerJobTestInt {
...
}
```

Maybe you need some annotations for a personal raison, so you can keep them